# Writing a distributed queue in Amazon's DynamoDB

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm looking to convert a large directory of high resolution images (several million) into thumbnails using Python. I have a DynamoDB table that stores the location of each image in S3.

Instead of processing all these images on one EC2 instance (would take weeks) I'd like to write a distributed application using a bunch of instances.

What techniques could I use to write a queue that would allow a node to "check out" an image from the database, resize it, and update the database with the new dimensions of the generated thumbnails?

Specifically I'm worried about atomicity and concurrency -- how can I prevent two nodes from checking out the same job at the same time with DynamoDB?

Answer (score 11):

One approach you could take would be to use [Amazon's Simple Queue Service(SQS)](http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) in conjunction with DynamoDB. So what you could do is write messages to the queue that contain something like the hash key of the image entry in DynamoDB.  Each instance would periodically check the queue and grab messages off.  When an instance grabs a message off the queue, it becomes invisible to other instances for a given amount of time.  You can then look up and process the image and delete the message off the queue.  If for some reason something goes wrong with processing the image, the message will not be deleted and it will become visible for other instances to grab.

Another, probably more complicated, approach would be to use DynamoDB's [conditional update mechanism](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithDDItems.html#WorkingWithItemsConditionalUpdate) to implement a locking scheme.  For example, you could add something a 'beingProcessed' attribute to your data model, that is either 0 or 1.  The first thing an instance could do is perform a conditional update on this column, changing the value to 1 iff the initial value is 0.  There is probably more to do here around making it a proper/robust locking mechanism....

Comment: DynamoDB is the wrong tool for the job. The process is very simple w/ SQS.
1. DynamoDB =LargeImageLocations> SQS;
SQS =Process> n*EC2 =UpdateLocation> DynamoDB

Comment: The sentence "SQS has a built in mechanism to prevent multiple instances from reading the same message" is a bit misleading. There is no "once-only" guarantee. I see you describe a locking solution with DynamoDB, but better remove the above statement.

Comment: Note that SQS is not HIPAA compliant, so what nstehr suggests may be a very viable solution if you are not allowed to store certain information in the SQS message itself.

Comment: Be warned. SQS has many draw backs and corner cases that bit me hard. The de-duplication is still active even after deleting the message if your use fifio and has a limit of 300 transactions per sec (not very scaleable..). If you try to use standard queues, SQS has a nasty habit of dropping sent messages and duplicating messages at random with no warning. 

Sad to say but DynamoDb based queuing is a lot more stable and scale-able. Plus you can scan whats going on in your queue :) +1 for control freaks like me

Answer (score 3):

Using DynamoDB's optimistic locking with versioning would allow a node to "check out" a job by updating a status field to "InProgress".  If a different node tried checking out the same job by updating the status field, it would receive an error and would know to retrieve a different job.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/JavaVersionSupportHLAPI.html

I know this is an old question, so this answer is more for the community than the original poster.

Comment: Using dynamo this way leads to issues if your process dies midway through and the in progress flag never gets cleared.

Comment: The "InProgress" shouldn't be a flag but a timestamp. Another job scans periodically to ensure that all jobs finished within a window of time allotted for the job, otherwise trigger a retry or an alert.

Answer (score 0):

A good/cool approach is to use **EMR** for this. There is an inter-connection layer in EMR to connect HIVE to DynamoDB. You can then walk through your Table almost as you would with a SQL one and perform your operations.

There is a pretty **good guide for it** here: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/EMRforDynamoDB.html

It for import/export but can be easily adapted.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, DynamoDB released parallel scan:
http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/05/amazon-dynamodb-parallel-scans-and-other-good-news.html

Now, 10 hosts can read from the same table at the same time, and DynamoDB guarantees they won't see the same items.